# thumbs_up gem to sort liked posted - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the thumbs_up gem to allow users to like designs and products. In the users profile, i have it showing all of the designs and products that the user has liked. Right now, i have concatenated the designs and products into one view but they are ordered 'created_at DESC' for the designs+products. I want to order it based on when the user voted so when a user votes on a design, it's first on their profile. Here is the code i have

in the model

```
def favorites
  Design.joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ?', self.id).where('voteable_type = ?', 'Design').where('vote = ?', true)
end

def favs
  Product.joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ?', self.id).where('voteable_type = ?', 'Product').where('vote = ?', true)
end
```

in the controller

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
@designs = @user.favorites
@products = @user.favs

@favorites = @designs.to_a.concat @products.to_a
@favorites.sort! {|t1, t2| t2.created_at <=> t1.created_at}
```

I've even removed the default scope for designs and products in case that was the issue but it didn't resolve it.

i've also tried this with no luck

```
Design.joins(:votes).where('voter_id = ?', self.id).where('voteable_type = ?', 'Design').where('vote = ?', true).order('created_at DESC')
```

there is a timestamp 'created_at' that belongs to each vote. so i know this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If a user `has_many :votes`, votes `belong_to :voteable` and every user only votes on a specific `voteable` once, I would try something like this:

```
@user.votes.includes(:voteable).order('created_at DESC')
```

This will return collection of votes ordered by their create date. Then you can iterate over them and display their `voteable` attribute however you want. If you only want designs and not products then you will need to do a join instead of `includes` and filter by `voteable_type`